# How to return all task with google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some codes to return the tasks in one of my tasklist.
Problem is that it is only returning only 19 task at a time. It that normal if so how to I work around it

Code is use are

```
  var tasks=Tasks.Tasks.list(tasklistID);
  return tasks
```

Comment: How many should it return?

Comment: The are over 100 task in the list. This is supposed to generate an array of all the tasks that it then filtrered to give today's task

Comment: Then you probably need to use the nextPageToken and go through all of the pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to retrieve all tasks from a task list using Google Apps Script.
- The task list has over 100 tasks.
- You have already been able to use Tasks API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modified script?

#### Modification points:

- At `Tasks.Tasks.list()`, `maxResults` is 20 as the default.

  - In your case, it uses `maxResults: 100` which is the maximum value. By this, it can reduce the number of API calls.
- When over 100 tasks are retrieved, the property of `nextPageToken` is required to be used.

  - This has mentioned by [Cooper's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615087/how-to-return-all-task-with-google-script#comment99805358_56615087).

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var tasklistId = "###"; // Please set this.

var list = [];
var pageToken = "";
do {
   var res = Tasks.Tasks.list(tasklistId, {maxResults: 100, pageToken: pageToken});
   Array.prototype.push.apply(list, res.items);
   pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
} while (pageToken);

Logger.log(list) // You can retrieve all tasks with "list".
```

#### Note:

- When you use this script, please enable Tasks API at Advanced Google Services.
- Although this has not been mentioned, if you want to retrieve all tasks including the completed tasks, please modify `var res = Tasks.Tasks.list(tasklistId, {maxResults: 100, pageToken: pageToken})` as follows.

  - `var res = Tasks.Tasks.list(tasklistId, {maxResults: 100, pageToken: pageToken, showHidden: true})`

#### Reference:

- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Tasks: list](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/list)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.